# Validate commit hash from the input (workflow_dispatch)

Tags: git, github-actions, git-commit

I want to validate a commit hash that is coming from the input ([workflow_dispatch](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-06-github-actions-manual-triggers-with-workflow_dispatch/)):

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
  - name: Checkout Project
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
  - name: Run only if input exist (Validate input hash)
    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.sha != '' }}
    run: git cat-file -e ${{ github.event.inputs.sha }}^{commit}
```

Problem is that it only works for the latest commit.

If I use any other commit, it says:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name COMMIT_HASH^{commit}
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

But it works locally. I also tried this way:

```
git cat-file -e ${{ github.event.inputs.sha }}
git cat-file commit ${{ github.event.inputs.sha }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run `git rev-list HEAD` in order to check the commit history and it turns out it only displayed the latest commit.

That's because [checkout action](https://github.com/actions/checkout) only retrieves a single commit by default, for the ref/SHA that triggered the workflow. We can set up `fetch-depth: 0` to fetch all history for all branches and tags:

```
  - name: Checkout Project
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
```

This way, the code on my question will work.